# MySQL Pivot turn record to coloumn with all data listed

Tags: mysql, sql, database, pivot

Hello I have this kind of table.

```
svcid hostid fieldname      fieldval                           date_chk
  1    9205    rawdata      raw data                           2018-07-27 05:14:47
  1    9205    rawdata      raw data                           2018-07-27 05:14:57
  1    9205    rawdata      raw data                           2018-07-27 05:20:24
  1    9205    dummyoutput  echo "you have running dummy.sh!"  2018-07-27 05:20:24
  1    9205    rawdata      raw data                           2018-07-27 05:21:04
  1    9205    dummyoutput  echo "you have running dummy.sh!"  2018-07-27 05:21:04
```

And I want to turn into this

```
svcid hostid  rawdata    dummyoutput                           date_chk
  1    9205   raw data   null                                  2018-07-27 05:14:47
  1    9205   raw data   null                                  2018-07-27 05:14:57
  1    9205   raw data   echo "you have running dummy.sh!"     2018-07-27 05:20:24
  1    9205   raw data   echo "you have running dummy.sh!"     2018-07-27 05:21:24
```

For future information [I already create sql fiddle in here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dfab89/1/0)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this. *Aggregate function condition*

use `CASE WHEN` with `MAX` function and `group by`

```
SELECT svcid,
       hostid,
       max(CASE WHEN fieldname = 'rawdata' THEN fieldval  END), 
       max(CASE WHEN fieldname = 'dummyoutput' THEN fieldval  END),
       date_chk
FROM tb_service_out_monitor
GROUP BY  svcid,
       hostid,
       date_chk
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dfab89/4)

Comment: that was quick!
thanks, I will read more, previously I already try this method using max() but only latest data were displayed, I don't know multiple group by value will make it liste
again thanks!